# Messed up DLL structure in a Visual Basic program

Tags: vb.net, dll

I was trying to install JSON.NET for a VB.NET program earlier, the .dll file I can import just fine, but Visual Studio does not recognize the .pdb file that comes with it. While searching for a solution to this, I have changed some of the debug settings and possibly dll settings too but I still couldn't get the JSON.NET library to work.

I was getting frustrated and have decided to make my own method to parse a JSON file. But now, having done some weird operations on stackoverflow previously, simple code that would have been valid throws an error, like:

`Dim strs() as String = {"dog", "cat"}`

would throw

`System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "dog" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'`

Before the program executes, it has a log of:

```
'BrokerNotifier.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'BrokerNotifier.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'E:\Repository\Visual Basic\BrokerNotifier\BrokerNotifier\bin\Release\BrokerNotifier.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'BrokerNotifier.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: BrokerNotifier.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'BrokerNotifier.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: BrokerNotifier.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'BrokerNotifier.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: BrokerNotifier.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'BrokerNotifier.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: BrokerNotifier.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'BrokerNotifier.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: BrokerNotifier.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'BrokerNotifier.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: BrokerNotifier.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'BrokerNotifier.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: BrokerNotifier.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'BrokerNotifier.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: BrokerNotifier.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Conversion from string "dog" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

What do I need to do to solve this? I have no deep knowledge of Visual Basic like .dll files or how code works together in the .NET framework. I just recently came from a Java and C++ background so assume I know nothing of the .NET framework. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the .pdb file. It contains debug info. If the library throws an exception, this this would enable the exception to contain source line info.

Also use the packet manager instead of referencing DLLs manually:

- Start by removing the current json DLL reference.
- Right click the project in Visual Studio.
- Select "Manage NuGet Packages..."
- Switch to the "Browse" tab.
- Enter "json" in the search field. You will get a long list of json related stuff.
- Select "Newtonsoft.Json" in this list (if it is the library you are using).
- Klick the button "Install".

Et voilà! This also has the advantage that the package manger show you updates and allows you to install them by a single click.

---

In the case that your solution is corrupt:

Create a new solution and add all of your old source code as existing items. Be careful with Forms and custom or user controls. Add them one-by-one and add only the *.vb file, not the *.designer.vb and not the *.resx file. The latter fiels will be added automatically by Visual Studio.

---

In the case that Visual Studio itself is corrupt:

Launch the Visual Studio installer and select the Repair option.

Comment: Thanks, but the main question is to how to recover from my flawed Visual Studio after I have messed with some .dll files. Still a great answer.